# Assign arr with numpy fancy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I really hope this is not a duplicate and this is probably a very stupid question. Sorry ;)

Problem: 
I have a greyscale image with values/classes 1 and 2 and I want to convert/map this to a color image where 1 equals yellow and 2 equals blue.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

result=cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

result[result==2]=[15,100,100]

result[result==1]=[130,255,255]
```

But this is failing with the error `ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 1995594 output values where the mask is true`

I think I very close to the solution, but I don't get it. 
Thanks in Advance for your help!

Comment: you don't need an image to demonstrate this problem. mock up a simple 5 x 5 array to mess around with

Comment: That's true. I tried it, but the problem is the same. np.where does not work, too. `np.where(result==2,np.array([15,100,100]), result)`

Comment: Have you checked the shape of `result`? Spoiler: `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`.

Comment: Yes, it has the dimension of my Image and the values as I described.

Comment: you are assigning a color to gray-scale image, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @gboffi i got an answer. I guess I was hoping that there is a more pythonic way of doing this, but ok.

```py
# Load in Image File
img=cv2.imread("imgfile", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# Create new array with the shape of the original image
color=np.zeros((img.shape[0],result.shape[1],3))
# Note that opencv needs BGR and values from 0..1
color[result==1]=(0.84,117/225,2/225)
color[result==2]=(78/225,173/225,240/225)
```

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a Numpy array and is *typed*, its type being an integer and you try to assign to an integer slot a triple of integers… no good.

What you want to do is creating an empty color image, with the same dimensions of `result`, and assigning to the last axis the requested triples.

I have not installed `cv2` but you can look at the following code to have an idea on how to proceed.

Equivalent to what you have done, the same error

```
In [36]: import numpy as np                                                               
In [37]: a = np.random.randint(0,2,(2,4))                                                 
In [38]: a                                                                                
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
In [39]: a[a==1] = (1,2,3)                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-24af4c8dbf5a> in <module>
----> 1 a[a==1] = (1,1)

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 2 input values to the 3 output values where the mask is true
```

Now, allocate a 3D array and apply indexing to it, assigning by default to the last axis

```
In [40]: b = np.zeros((2,4,3))                                                            
In [41]: b[a==1] = (1,2,3)                                                                
In [42]: b                                                                                
Out[42]: 
array([[[1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 2., 3.]]])
```

We have two inner matrices (corresponding to the two rows of `a`), in each matrix four rows (corresponding to the four columns of `a`) and finally the columns are the RGB triples that you need.

I don't know exactly how the data is arranged in a `cv2` image but I think you have to do minor adjustements, if any at all.